# Git pulling remote changes into local without creating a new merge commit

Tags: git

I am trying to learn git, I have forked and cloned a repo (say someRepo) and added the mainRepo as an upstream to my forked repo (forkedRepo) in my local. Both the repos have a develop branch. Say someone pushed some commits - say C1,C2 onto the mainRepo, and I have some local, unpushed commits say L1,L2 which I don't plan to push. How do I get C1 and C2 and still keep L1 and L2 in a clean way ? I tried git merge previously, but that ended up creating a new merge commit, which I want to avoid. Thanks !

to clarify, here is what my git remote looks like

```
git remote -v
origin  git@github.paypal.com:myFork/someRepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.paypal.com:myFork/someRepo.git (push)
upstream        git@github.paypal.com:mainRepo/someRepo.git (fetch)
upstream        git@github.paypal.com:mainRepo/someRepo.git (push)
```

Now if someone pushed C1, C2 onto develop of mainRepo, how do I get them onto my local develop of myFork, keeping my commits L1,L2 on my local develop intact

Comment: Do you want to publish your branch later and expect it to be integrated into the main repo at some point? If so, it is better to merge the required commits, or you rebase your work on the upstream. If not, use `git cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best options briefly described are

- `git merge L1` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

As you mentioned, this will create a merge commit which is good practice. This represents your historic events most accurately and would be my personal preferred way. Why do you want to avoid merge commits? Maybe you are not fully aware of the benefits and it feels they "pollute" your history? If that's the case, I would recommend working with them and start reading more about branching and merging. If you plan repeating this action on a regular basis, I would highly recommend merge as default strategy.

- `git rebase L1 --onto C1` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

In a nutshell, this takes your local branch and tries to re-create all your commits based on L1. If you find merge conflicts on the way, you have to fix them. This simulates that all your changes would have been made after L1.

- `git cherry-pick <commit>` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

This takes a single commit and puts into onto your branch. Especially useful, if you want to pick a single change one time only.

You will find much more details and examples in the official docs. I can also recommend https://learngitbranching.js.org/ for learning.